# Disprove if $a_n$ converges then $a_{n+1}/a_n$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Disprove: if $a_n$ converges then $a_{n+1}/a_n$ converges.

I want to disprove this statement but I couldn't find a sequence that disproves it.

Further more it will be really helpful to know what are the things to look for in those kind of questions.

Comment: What about taking $a_n=1/n$?

Comment: You may wish to edit your title : it seems to be missing a `$`.  Also, although I agree with the prior comments, I should point out that they are **guessing** that your intent re $a_n + 1 / a_n$ is $a_n + (1/a_n).$  I recommend also clarifying this.

Comment: @Bungo : somewhat depends on OP's intent, re my previous comment : anyway, you can't divide by zero.

Comment: @Bungo I disagree here.  I think that the query's assertion does make sense (assuming that my interpretation guess is accurate); it is merely that the query's assertion, while making sense, is **false**.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong title.. new here :/, I actually meant $a_{n+1}$ / $an$

Comment: @EeveeTrainer You are being asked to hit a moving target.

Comment: @Bungo You are being asked to hit a moving target.

Comment: Thanks to all for the feedback.  My carelessness in posting an inaccurate answer.  I have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** We could try $ 1, , 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, \ldots$ but the sequence doesn't converge.
The ratio is $  1, -1, 1, -1, \ldots$ which doesn't converge.

Modify it so that the sequence converges, but the ratio doesn't.

---

Things to look for

- What could make the ratio not converge? Could we make it arbitrarily large?
- If $ a_n \rightarrow L \neq 0$, prove that $ \frac{ a_n } { a_{n-1}} \rightarrow 1$. (This should be obvious after playing around with it for a while.)
- Hence, if we want a counter example, what must be true of $ L$?
- So we know now that $ a_n \rightarrow 0$. Can the ratio of small terms be arbitraily large?

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$a_n = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n} & \text{if }n\text{ is even} \\
\frac{1}{n^2} & \text{if }n\text{ is odd} \\
\end{cases}$$
Then $a_n \to 0$, but
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \begin{cases}
\frac{n}{(n+1)^2} < \frac{1}{n} & \text{if }n\text{ is even} \\
\frac{n^2}{n+1} \geq \frac{n}{2} & \text{if }n\text{ is odd} \\
\end{cases}$$
Hence $\lim a_{n+1}/a_n$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If a sequence, $b_n$, is equidistributed in $[-1, 1]$ (or a smaller interval), then $a_n = \prod_{k=1}^n b_k$ would converge to $0$, while $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = b_{n+1}$ does not converge.

For example, take $b_n = \sin(n) \to a_n = \prod_{k=1}^n \sin(k)$. Then $a_n \to 0$, but $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ does not exist.